# Android - SlideMenu and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have followed a tutorial to create step by step a sliding menu and it works, but looking in the code I have noticed that when users touch a menu item the code will run this piece of code:

MainActivity:

```
....
/**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }
/**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:{
                fragment = new PersonaggiPrincipali();
                break;
            }
            case 1:{
                fragment = new PersonaggiSecondari();
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                fragment = new Video();
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
....
```

Basically it call a new `Class` when the item is clicked.
The class is formed in this way:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PersonaggiPrincipali extends Fragment {

    public PersonaggiPrincipali(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personaggi_principali, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

So it just return the layout and the `displayView` function above will replace the current with the returned one, right?

```
if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
....
}
```

My question is, in the view returned how can I manipulate it if the class is just a return of the layout?

For example, let's assume that in the returned view I have a `Button` and I need to set a ClickListener or just create a function that will chenge the Activity (activity that should be insert in the main view with the SlidingMenu), How can I do that?

Should I write all the code in the `MainActivity` to manage that?

Comment: Ciao Christian, when you instantiate a Fragment you don't get a view as a result but a Fragment. If your Fragment has some Button you can set the listeners in the onCreateView method of the Fragment.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I need, If you create an aswer I will accept it!

Comment: Glad it helped, I've just posted my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao Christian, when you instantiate a `Fragment` you don't get a view as a result but a `Fragment`.

The `onCreateView` method is just part of the lifecycle of a fragment and that's where you have to return the main view of your fragment. Also, if your fragment has a `Button` you can set the listener in the `onCreateView` method of the Fragment.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)

Example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personaggi_principali, container, false);

    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_BUTTON_ID);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // do you stuff here...
            }
        });

    return rootView;
}
```

Please notice the Button in the example is just a local variable, if you need to access it later, it's better to declare it as a class variable.

Regarding communication (`Fragment` to `Fragment`, host `Activity` to `Fragment`), I think everything you need to know is well explained in the official documentation: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: wow ho visto il tuo profilo, complimenti per i lavori svolti! Posso contattarti via mail per un paio di problemi riscontrati con l'applicazione snai?

Comment: grazie, certo, nessun problema.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do it in the same (`onCreateView()`) method. Additionally, you could include private references to Views inside your fragment layout in your `PersonaggiPrincipali` class. Also implement get() methods for these Views and you can change them from your `MainActivity`.
For example:

```
public class PersonaggiPrincipali extends Fragment {
     private Button fragButton;
     public PersonaggiPrincipali(){}

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personaggi_principali, container, false);
         fragButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragButtonId); //replace R.id.fragButtonId with the appropriate Id from your xml layout
         return rootView;
     }
     public Button getFragButton() {
         return this.fragButton;
     }
}
```